# I need to understand this LSTM and Masking layers result

Tags: keras, lstm, chatbot, recurrent-neural-network

I'm new at keras lstm could you please explain to me this model.summary()
in rasa core training

![model after training][1]

Also, what is the `Masking` layer doing and what does the value `-1` in it mean?

Comment: What do you want to know exactly?

Comment: I edited the Q with code i wanna know what is masking -1 and what the param mean in result and do batch shape calculate the two parameters to produce size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Masking` layer is meant to "ignore steps" in sequences.

Your LSTM is working with sequences of 5 steps and 42 features per step.
If all features in a step have the same value defined in `Masking` (`-1` in the example), that step will be ignored during training.

The idea is to simulate variable length sequences.

Comment: thanks alot, what it does mean when they said only the last output from the rnn is used to calculate the loss if the outshape =1 and if =2 all the outputs from the rnn are used to calculate the loss, therefore a sequence is returned and time distributed layer is used

Comment: RNNs discard the steps when you use `return_sequences = False` - output shape `(batch, units)`; --- and keep the steps in the output when you use `return_sequences = True` - output shape `(batch, steps, units)`.

Comment: I'm doing a research project on bots with ai framwork just want to understand a keras lstm based model architecture would you please help me? i can send code for the model i just want an overview explain

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly, what exactly you don't understand but model.summary()

> prints a summary representation of your model. (keras.io)

It lists all layers used in the given model with its respective size.
This particular model obviously starts with a masking layer for input sequences (I guess because of padding) and is followed by the simplest LSTM model possible.

Comment: I edited the Q with code i wanna know what is masking -1 and what the param mean in result and do batch shape calculate the two parameters to produce size?